# Prevent access of default constructor of base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, serialization, default-constructor

I have a base class and a derived class. As both the classes are serializable, it require to have default constructor. But I want to prevent access of default constructor of base class because it may cause a problem if someone will create object with default constructor. I cannot make it as private or internal as it is base class. Making it private shows error in derived class. The error is base does not have any parameterless constructor. How can I prevent access of default constructor of base class? Below is the sample code.

```
[Serializable]
public class Test1()
{
    public Test1()
    {

    }

    public Test1(int i, int j)
    {

    }

    public Test1(int i, int j, int k)
    {

    }
 }

[Serializable]
public class Test2():Test1
{
    public Test2():base()
    {

    }

    public Test2(int i, int j):base(i,j)
    {

    }

    public Test2(int i, int j, int k):base(i,j,k)
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `protected`? This is the access modifier that makes something visible only to derived classes.

Comment: Making it protected allows me to access default constructor

Answer (score 1):

Use `protected` .

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member
>   is accessible within its class and by derived class instances. For a
>   comparison of protected with the other access modifiers.

```
public class Test1()
{
    protected Test1()
    {

    }

    public Test1(int i, int j)
    {

    }

    public Test1(int i, int j, int k)
    {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and throw exception in `Constructor` as `Serializer` **won't** use it. If anybody uses he's the culprit :p

```
[Serializable]
public class Test1()
{
    public Test1()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Default constructor shouldn't be used")
    }

    public Test1(int i, int j)
    {

    }

    public Test1(int i, int j, int k)
    {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched several issue for this case. One solution to almost own it's to use obsolete anotaion with paramater to true for building fail.

```
...
    [Serializable]
    public class Test2():Test1
    {
        [Obsolete("Don't use the default constructor.", true)]
        public Test2():base()
        {

        }
...
```

Comment: This is the best idea if OP wants to do it in `Test2` class but it seems op need to do it in `Test1`(base class). If he do that then compiler will not allow you to invoke `Test2():base()`

Comment: absolutely, in this case you can just generate a warning with switching boolean flag. Or if Test1 class is just a technical class you declare it in abstract and you prevent to call base constructor directly.